# Just discovered that I lost a very important folder

Tags: files, data-recovery, undelete

I had a folder with some very important files in it. Overnight it somehow vanished. The diskspace is low on said drive ... it's a 1TB and running at about 90% capasity. They were personal files of my kids singing and other tracks from a  studio I once owned.  I have since written to the drive and that worries me for the fact that I may have done more damage than good. Any help with this would be greatly appreciated. I called a data recovery company and they said it could cost anywhere upto $2500.00

Comment: If it's somehow magically vanished but the free space on that disk did not increased, then I believe that your file are still there. What is the format of that disk? if it's `NTFS`, connect your drive to a windows system, then run `check disk` on that drive.

Comment: You may want to consider removing the drive as an emergency preventive measure.  That would prevent the operating system from writing to the hard drive.  You can then connect your drive on another computer to inspect it with a data recovery tool.

Comment: Gosh, if it is NTFS **do not** run `chkdsk`. But yeah, please tell us about the file system that you use on the drive.

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure your files got deleted, or think your drive might be dying, this can be a huge topic (data recovery can get very complex, very fast).

However, **before you do ANYTHING, make an image of your drive**. 
You always want to work/try recovery tools on an image, not the actual drive, just in case things go wrong (the image will contain deleted files that can be recovered exactly as the actual drive).

To do this, install **ddrescue**. I'm assuming this is not the drive your system is on? 
As it has to be unmounted for this, if it is, do the following steps booted from a LiveCD.

```
sudo apt-get install ddrescue
```

Now unmount your drive, and find out what your drives path is with

```
sudo parted -l | less
```

and look for it, write down it's device name (under Disk, as in /dev/sdX)

Next, make sure you have enough space left somewhere, as much as the original drives size (the image will be the same) and run ddrescue to create an image from it, the command is:

```
ddrescue -d <drive-to-rescue> <img-to-store> <logfile>
```

As in

```
sudo ddrescue -d /dev/path-to-your-drive /path/to/image.img /path/to/image.log
```

It will now create an image of the drive, **this can take a long time** (if the drive is damaged, it might have to retry several times). In case you want to stop it, you can, as long as you restart it pointing to the same image and logfile, it should continue where it left off.

Once this is done, unplug your original drive, don't use it anymore (don't write on it especially), try your recovery on the image instead, where things can't go wrong as easily.

As for recovery, that's a little too much to cover here (it's a huge topic). And there are various tools depending on what the files you deleted were, for example **foremost** is a great starting point for photos, as is **scalpel**. What tools you want to try, depends on the files you are trying to recover however. 
But you can run these on the image file now, instead of the drive. As in

```
sudo scalpel image-of-your-drive.img -o path/to/output-directory
```

I'd recommend checking https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DataRecovery
as well as the forensic wiki http://forensicswiki.org/wiki/Main_Page for starters.

Good Luck!

Comment: Great point about imaging the drive, but I would keep file carvers as the *last* resort rather than a starting point.

Comment: You're right, i just assumed he was at that point, since he mentioned contacting a data recovery company already. Was just trying to make sure he knows about imaging the drive first, and doesn't start running tools on the (possibly damaged) drive directly.